# Python: Custom package delivered with script and ways of importing it

Tags: python

I am trying to grok the way packages work in Python. My goal is to only require that Python is installed, the users should simply be able to check out the script repository and run it.

The relevant files (output of `ls TestPackage.py Mypackage/`):

```
TestPackage.py

Mypackage/:
__init__.py
SomeClass.py
```

Contents of **TestPackage.py**:

```
from Mypackage import SomeClass

print "Hello from TestPackage.py"

the_instance = SomeClass()

the_instance.hi()
```

Contents of Mypackage/**_*init*_.py**:

```
class InsideInitPy():
    def hi(self):
        print "Hi from InsideInitPy! (when importing package)"

InsideInitPy().hi()
```

Contents of Mypackage/**SomeClass.py**:

```
class SomeClass():
    def hi(self):
        print "Hi from SomeClass in the package! (using explicit call)"
```

When running the test script `python TestPackage.py`:

```
Hi from InsideInitPy! (when importing package)
Hello from TestPackage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestPackage.py", line 5, in <module>
    the_instance = SomeClass()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The line producing an error is `the_instance = SomeClass()`. As `Hi from InsideInitPy! (when importing package)` is written to the console when importing it seems the package can be found.

How do I get the example working (as well as pros and cons to) using these variants of first line in `TestPackage.py` with:

1. `from Mypackage import SomeClass`
2. `from Mypackage import *`
3. `import Mypackage`

Does it affect the import if the user is standing in the same directory as TestPackage.py or not?

Comment: Python's error messages are informative. If you get `'module' object is not callable` then you are calling a module object.

Comment: Well I still didn´t understand why I couldn´t call it.

Comment: I´ll gain the knowledge to answer my three questions above and post an answer. Even though the provided answers helped me they didn´t answer the original question. I´ll take the time to write a longer answer myself later on, as it might help someone else when getting a hit on this question when searching.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "didn't answer the original question". Both answers certainly did!

Comment: (which is not to discourage you from writing up your own answer -- that's a good idea =)

Comment: @katrielalex: I have seen the three import variants mentioned in my list in the question.  I was looking for a short _"To make it work that way you...and it´s a good/bad idea to do it because..."_ for those three alternatives. I haven´t found it explained succinctly elsewhere on the web.

Comment: But your three ways are all wrong -- they all give you access to the _module_ `SomeClass` not the _class_ `SomeClass`!

Comment: @katrielalex: All right! Thanks for clarifying it again! I guess I was curious about how to organize classes so that I won´t have to import them each. I know it is a clear, straight-forward way to do it, but I only have a few utility classes so I thought it would be convenient for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't confuse classes with modules.**

You have a file `SomeClass.py`. Files correspond to modules. So `import SomeClass` gives you a *module*.

Inside `SomeClass.py` you have a class definition. That class is `SomeClass.SomeClass`. So you would need to write

```
the_instance = SomeClass.SomeClass()
```

Alternatively, you could import the class `SomeClass` from the module `MyPackage.SomeClass`:

```
from MyPackage.Someclass import SomeClass
```

Answer (score 3):

Python is not Java.

```
from Mypackage.SomeClass import SomeClass
```